# ArgumentException when trying to open a SqlConnection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

This code is for the button:
But every time i run it say's `ArgumentException was unhandled by user code`.

It's a site made to look up in at Database to see if there is enough ink.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Toner Values('"+txtFname.Text+"','"+txtLname.Text+"','"+TxtCity.Text+"')",con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Indsætning succesfuld!!!";
        TxtCity.Text = "";
        txtFname.Text = "";
        txtLname.Text = "";
    }
    protected void TextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You must be more specific when using stackoverflow. What line is your code breaking on?

Comment: are you using LINQTOSQL??

Comment: Its breaking on 
'SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);'
And no i dont use LINQTOSQL.
I just made a Database local..

Comment: Are you sure that "ConnectionString" exists as a Connection String within your web.config?

Comment: <Insert arbitrary SQL injection comment here>

Comment: Add your <connectionStrings> section in web.config to the question...

Comment: CodeCaster mean that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. That is, you can write special things in the input fields that changes the SQL in a way that can do bad things to your database (like delete etc.) You should use command parameters instead. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Comment: Among others, you open the connection and you do not close it.! And also you open it without using it on page load, again you do not close it.

Comment: yes i did con.Close();

Comment: Are you sure your connectionString is "ConnectionString" when you launch debug?
You should provide your web.config for more info.

Comment: <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jlin.EFIF\Documents\Database1.accdb"
      providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="asdasdConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jlin.EFIF\Desktop\asdasd.mdb"
      providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: When reporting an exception, always report the _complete_ exception. If necessary, temporarily surround the code in question with a try/catch block, and `try {...} catch (Exception ex){Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); throw;}` or the equivalent.

Comment: For diagnostic purposes, try moving the connection string initialization into your `Button1_Click` method; also move the `con.Open();` Add `string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;` then `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);` then stop in the debugger and see what the value of `cs` is, and post the full exception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My best guess is that `TxtCity` should be `txtCity`.

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "insert into Toner Values (@Fname, @Lname, @City)";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        //Use parameterized query to prevent SQL injection
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtFname.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtLname.Text;
        //C# is case-sensitive... is it txtCity or TxtCity?
        cmd.Parameters.Add("City", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TxtCity.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Indsætning succesfuld!!!";
        TxtCity.Text = "";
        txtFname.Text = "";
        txtLname.Text = "";
    }
}
```